# Limit of sequence w\ floor function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

prove:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} n^2 \lfloor a/n \rfloor = 0$

a is real.

I know

$a/n - 1 \lt \lfloor a/n \rfloor \le a/n$

but I dont see how it helps me. I want to try to prove it by defintion, but I dont see what N I should take (such that for every n>N...).

please give me hint!

thanks

Comment: When $n>a$,  $\lfloor a/n \rfloor=0$.

Comment: a is real, so n>|a|. I tried it but I want to write |a_n-0|<.... but because of n^2 it |a_n-0|>...

Comment: Sorry, my previous statement was not quite complete: it works if $a \geqslant 0$. If $0<-a<n$, $\lfloor a/n \rfloor=-1$, assuming the usual definition, in which case the result is false.

Comment: so I dont see what am i supppose to do :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, when $a<0$, the result is false, since if $-a<n$, $\lfloor a/n \rfloor = -1$.

For $a \geqslant 0$, when $n$ becomes large enough, we end up with $n>a$, and so $0 \leqslant a/n<1$ and $\lfloor a/n \rfloor = 0$, since the floor function gives us the largest integer smaller than or equal to its argument. Then the sequence goes
$$ \lfloor a \rfloor \dotsc,(k-1)^2,k^2,0,0,0,\dotsc, $$
where $k-1<a \leqslant k$, and all subsequent terms are zero, so the limit must be zero.